# Get fractional portion of currency value

Tags: javascript, regex

The String : `$ 22.4969694`
Regex Expression : `([.])+`

I've tried `.test()`, but I'm not trying to get a boolean response, I'm trying to get the length number of the `.` character and slice it.

So if `.` is detected in the string, it will slice `$ 22.` off the string and set the variable value to `4969694`.

Comment: You have to escape the dot, \.   On its own, it is a wildcard that will match any character.

Comment: Use the regex expression:  ([\.])+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a regex, it's quite straight forward

```js
var str1 = '$ 22.4969694';
var str2 = '$ 22694';

console.log( str1.split('.').pop() )  // 4969694
console.log( str2.split('.').pop() ); // nothing happens
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure that I follow what you want your final result(s) to look like but this is what I have come up with that may work for you.

Based on what values you want back this works.

```js
let vals = ['$ 22.4969694', '$ 22', '$ 22567.00']

vals.forEach(val => {
  let v = val.replace(/^.*\./, '')

  console.log(v)
})
```

Comment: Or:  val.replace(/^.*\./, '')   This will remove from the front of the string to the dot, if the dot exists.  If not, then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
const str = '$ 22.4969694';
const regex = /(\$)\s+(\d+)\.(\d+)/
```

`match` will return an array. The first element is the original string, and the remaining elements the matches. In this case the currency symbol, then the dollars, then the cents.

```
str.match(regex) // [ "$ 22.4969694", "$", "22", "4969694" ]
```

You can access these using normal array methods:

```
const m = str.match(regex);
console.log(m[3]); // 4969694
```